# Add properties to type from existing type

Tags: typescript

I have a type

```js
type Customer = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

Is it possible to create a type `EditableCustomer` from this type which looks like this?

```js
type EditableCustomer = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  onFirstNameChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
  onLastNameChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}
```

I'm thinking of a syntax like this:

```js
const customer:Customer = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
const editable: Editable<Customer> = customer
```

Comment: I think you can do: `type EditableCustomer<T> = {
value:T
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with help of [Key Remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types)

```js
type ChangeEvent<T> = T

type EditableCustomer = {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    onFirstNameChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
    onLastNameChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}


type Extend<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = keyof T extends string ? T & {
    [Prop in keyof T as `on${Capitalize<Prop & string>}Change`]: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
} : never

type Result = Extend<Customer>
```

See this line `on${Capitalize<Prop & string>}Change`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
type Customer = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

type EditableCustomer = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  onFirstNameChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
  onLastNameChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

type Editable<T> = EditableCustomer & T

const editable: Editable<Customer> = customer
```

Type `Editable` will hold all the properties of the `EditableCustomer` and also be extended with all the properties of `T`